# insert-ethers command not working on Linux Rocks frontend

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, rocks

After Rocks frontend being installed, I tried adding a new node to the frontend using the following command

```
#insert-ethers
```

but I got this error:

```
'bash: insert-ethers: command not found"
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

P.S: The server was installed by someone else so I`m guessing he maybe did not install all the necessary components.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be root to use the rocks commands. Try 
su -